# scala+spring seems to ignore Qualifier annotation

Tags: spring, scala, autowired

I have something like this:

```
class MyBean {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jdbcTemplate")
    @BeanProperty
    var jdbcTemplate : JdbcTemplate = null
}
```

Spring complains that it can't find a bean of type JdbcTemplate and refuses to autowire. My spring.xml has:

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

If I change the type of jdbcTemplate in MyBean from JdbcTemplate to SimpleJdbcTemplate then it works. My question is why is it apparently ignoring the Qualifier annotation? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `@Qualifier`. `SimpleJdbcTemplate` is not a subclass of `JdbcTemplate`, therefore it cannot be injected into a field of type `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: Lame. I assumed that JdbcTemplate was an interface and SimpleJdbcTemplate was a concrete implementation. My bad. Spring's naming is uncharacteristically crappy here though.